# Decomposing a vector space as eigenspaces by the action of a 3-cycle

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

edit: Let $V$ be a complex vector space

Consider a representation of the symmetric group on 3 letters: $$\gamma: S_3 \rightarrow End(V)$$. Let $\tau=(1,2,3) \in S_3$ be a 3-cycle, and consider the restricted representation of $\gamma$ to the subgroup generated by $\tau$. Can somebody explain to me how we obtain a decomposition: $$V = \oplus V_{\alpha}$$ of $V$ into eigenspaces for the action of $\tau$?

I really appreciate it!! Thanks!

Comment: Is the representation over $\mathbb{C}$? If so, then $\gamma(\tau)$ is diagonalizable, thus $V$ must be equal to the direct sum of its eigenspaces. (a standard result in linear algebra)

Comment: what makes $\gamma(\tau)$ diagonalizable?? Is it required that $\tau$ be a $3$-cycle??

Comment: Any abelian group is diagonalizable.

Comment: Interesting... Is that because in general the elements of any commutative subgroup of a matrix group are all diagonal matrices?

Comment: @HaKuNa MaTaTa No, it doesn't have to be a $3$-cycle. If $G$ is any finite group and $\rho: G\to GL(V)$ is a representation over $\mathbb{C}$ then $\rho(g)$ is diagonalizable for every $g\in G$. The reason: since $G$ is finite there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g^n=e$. Then we have $\rho(g)^n=\rho(g^n)=\rho(e)=I$. Hence the minimal polynomial of $\rho(g)$ divides the polynomial $x^n-1$, and thus it is separable. This implies $\rho(g)$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: @Mark, Nice explanation

Comment: To add to Mark's point, this proves that $\rho(g)$ is the sum of its eigenspaces. To go from here to any abelian group, one needs that if $A$ and $B$ are commuting matrices, then any eigenspace of $A$ is invariant under $B$. At that point, each eigenspace for $A$ breaks up as a sum of eigenspaces for $B$. Thus one can produce a basis of simultaneous eigenvectors for $A$ and $B$. Repeating this process yields the same for any (finite) abelian group.